# The best way to correlate NServiceBus response messages?

Tags: nservicebus, duplex

What would be the recommended way of correlating message replied to the original request?

Is there a way to tie the response to the original request that doesn't involve manually setting a property in the response message?

I mean I'm sure I can create a property called RequestId and set the OriginalRequestId to the response message, but this seems to be a bit of plumbing work that the framework should be able to handle.

If I can, is there a way to customize how the original Ids are generated? I'm trying to get away from having to persist the RequestId above in some persistence in order to create a context.

Comment: have you looked @ CorrelationId?

Comment: If the correlation ID isn't what you are after you may get what you need by using a header on the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NServiceBus, response messages contain a correlation id which is set to the same value as the id of the request message. This is how it works out of the box.